# What kind of bug is this?

Tags: bugs

[image]
I don't know what kind of bug this is but its weird, its slightly larger than a quarter. What kind of bug is this?

Comment: When I saw the question title, I thought it should be transferred to StackOveerflow SE.

Answer (score 2):

That is a camel spider, also known as a Solifugae.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae):

> The order includes more than 1,000 described species in about 153
>   genera. Despite the common names, they are neither true scorpions
>   (order Scorpiones) nor true spiders (order Araneae). Much like a
>   spider, the body of a solifugid has two tagmata: an opisthosoma
>   (abdomen) behind the prosoma (that is, in effect, a combined head and
>   thorax). At the front end, the prosoma bears two chelicerae that, in
>   most species, are conspicuously large. The chelicerae serve as jaws
>   and in many species also are used for stridulation. Unlike scorpions,
>   solifugids do not have a third tagma that forms a "tail". Most species
>   of Solifugae live in dry climates and feed opportunistically on
>   ground-dwelling arthropods and other small animals. The largest
>   species grow to a length of 12–15 cm (5–6 in), including legs. A
>   number of urban legends exaggerate the size and speed of the
>   Solifugae...

And there is not really a potential danger to humans. To learn more go to the following links

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae
https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/invertebrates/c/camel-spider/

Comment: It most certainly is a spider.  And you know your stuff David!  Yay!  Very excellent answer...you must have some entomology background, yes?  I am more impressed with insects, spiders...than with humans!  Grins.

Comment: "It most certainly is a spider. " it most certainly is not a spider.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have 8 legs and some kind of claws, which would make it an arachnid but not a spider, and given it has no stinging tail, I think it's a pseudoscorpion.

EDIT - here we are... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae